# Not able to transfer NFT from one chain to another using XCM

Tags: pallet, xcm, nft

I am attempting to convert the NFT ID into the form of MultiAssets in order to utilize XCM instructions for transferring it to another chain. However, I am only able to access the origin location and not the collection information.

```
let collection: MultiAssets T::CollectionIdConvert::convert(collection_id).into();

let value = (origin_location,collection );
ensure!(T::XcmTeleportFilter::contains(&value), Error::<T,I>::Filtered);
let assets: MultiAssets = collection.into();
```

I'm using this conversion because the collection id is not the type of MutliAssets.

```
type CollectionIdConvert: Convert<Self::CollectionId, MultiAssets>;
```

[image]

I've added a log in the value

After examining the log, it is evident that the MultiAsset does not contain any collection ID.

```
MultiLocation {
    parents: 0,
    interior: X1(
        AccountId32 {
            network: Some(
                Rococo,
            ),
            id: [ 28,189,45,67,83,10,68,112, 90, 208,136,175,49 
                  62,24,248, 11,83,239, 22, 179, 97, 119,205, 
                  75, 119, 184, 70, 242,      
            ] }, ), },
[],)
```

And when i'm teleporting assets from one chain to another it is able to show the both the assets and multilocation.

```
MultiLocation {
    parents: 0,
    interior: X1(
        AccountId32 {
            network: Some(
                Rococo,
            ),
            id: [28, 189, 45,67,83,10,68, 112,90,208,136,175,
                49, 62, 24, 248,11, 83, 239, 22, 179, 97, 119,
                205,  75, 119, 184, 70, 242,165, 240, 124,
            ],  }, ),},
[
    MultiAsset {
        id: Concrete(
            MultiLocation {
                parents: 0,
                interior: Here,
            },
        ),
        fun: Fungible(
            1000000000000000,
        ),
    },
],)
```

Can someone please guide me through this ?

Comment: let collection_id = fetch_collection_id_from_nft_id(nft_id); // Replace this with the actual method to retrieve the collection ID